# How can I ensure that a user has filled all required fields in a PreferenceFragment before allowing them to back out?

Tags: android, back, preferencefragment

I have a `PreferenceFragment` with a few preferences in it.  My aim is to ensure that the user fills in all of the values on this screen (they can leave if they fill none at all, but if you fill one in, you need to fill all in)

My first thought was that I could handle `onBackPressed` and check pref1, pref2, pref3, but it turns out that PreferenceFragments do not raise the `onBackPressed` or even an `onKeyDown` event.

I *could* handle it in the main Activity, but I have several such preference fragments loaded from the same activity, so it is ideal if I can handle the logic for each within the preference fragment itself.

If there is a better way to accomplish this, please explain.

Comment: Handle it from the activity. The data must be divorced from the view. That is one point of using fragments in the first place. Your activity is the controller. You must do the check from there.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - are you saying a PreferenceFragment constitutes a view and a PreferenceActivity is analogous to a controller? Sorry that sounds very odd or am I missing something, the [design philosophy](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) indicates that its logic should be as encapsulated as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you **CAN** handle it all in the Fragment.

I'll be talking in general terms because it seems you aren't a newbie dev.

1. provide a callback to the fragment instance in any method of your activity that signals the user wants to dismiss your `PreferenceFragment` like so:

   ```
   // The callback returns true if the user is allowed to exit the
   // preference screen and false otherwise
   // The PrefenceFragment will have to implement this interface/callback

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       if (mBackPressedCallback.onBackPressed)
           super.onBackPressed()
       ; else
           Toast.makeText("Fill in required prefence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show
           OR
           SnackBar.makeText(...).show
       ;
   }
   ```
2. Add an `OnSharedPrefenceChangeListener` on the `SharedPrefences` associated with your prefences file. Check how to do so here.
3. Create an array of boolean (or use some other data structure) to determine when a user has *satisfactorily* changed a preference of interest
4. When the `onBackPressed` callback is received, check that the array/ data structure is satisfactorly checked, return true if it is and false if it ain't